# Multliplication of std_logic_vector with Floating Point

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, fixed-point

I have 32 bit std_logic_vector signal and want to multiply it by floating point .

e.g

```
     signal Input : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0 );
     signal number = 0.2 ;
     signal Output: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0 ); 
     Output <= 0.2 * Input ;
```

What can be the best solution to do this kind of multiplication ? I have read somewhere that floating point arithmetic operation is not synthesizable so better to use fixed point numbers . How to do it ?

It would be appreciated if anyone can tell me the proper idea to do that sort of operation .

Thanks

Comment: Since you appear to be using Xilinx products: Maybe [this](http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/floating_pt.html) helps you?

Comment: You can use the Xilinx CoreGenerator and generate a floating point (mult) core or you just do it by hand as you learned it :).

Comment: @mkrieger1, thanks I will read about it ..

Comment: @Paebbels, can you please be more specific with respect to Vivado ? thanks

Comment: Xilinx ISE has a core generator, Vivado has a IP cataloge. Just select the core and configure it to your needs. Have s look at [PG0060](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/floating_point/v7_0/pg060-floating-point.pdf).

Comment: Yes . After your previous comment, I started searching that IP catalogue and @mkrieger also mentioned about that IP and I had used that very exact Floating Point IP. I added in my Block design and connected via DMA. I set the option "float to Fixed " in that IP (assuming I will send floating point value from SDK ).  After generating bitstream, I used the DMA function to send the value float 0.2 to TxBufferPtr, But unfortunately I see only 0 input and 0 output :( So floating point cannot be the input for sending value to DMA. 

What should I do to complete my required task :(

Comment: Further , I have read that " binary32 (Single Precision Format)
 – Uses 32  bits, with a 24-bit fraction and 8-bit 
exponent. " . So I send the value to DMA for S_AXIS for Floating Point IP "Value = 0x1001011". I can see the input on waveform ILA but my output of Floating Point is still "0000000".  (Note I select the option in IP float to fixed point ".)

Comment: Update : Using such option ; If I send 0.2 value , then I get 0, if I send 7.2 ; I get 7  and if  I send 7.82 , I get 8. 

So floating point input has some output but after rounding off the number as IP has float-fixed point operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" solution depends on the precision you need and resources you can afford (logic vs DSPs). Using floating point requires to convert `input` to floating point, loosing up to 8 bits in the process, do the multiplication and convert back. It cost a lot, too much if you ask me.

Using fixed point is pretty straightforward. Multiply `number` by 2^N, round that number, use it to multiply `input` and divide the result by 2^N. Take N = 8 for example:

```
number = 0.2
number_fixed = round(0.2*2^8) = 51
output = floor(51*input/2^8) -- If you add 2^N-1 before floor, you reduce your error
```

[That last comment is because `floor(m + 0.5) = round(m)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Rounding), it is usually cheap to do so, espicially in Xilinx since their multiplier have also an embedded adder/accumulator.

The problem with fixed point is the error. We multiplied by `51/256` instead of `0.2`, yielding a difference of `0.00078125`. If `input` was `1000000`, then the error committed is 781. This can be fixed by using a bigger `N`, which cost more hardware. Also, `0.2` does not have a closed form in binary: `0.2 = 0.0011001100110011...`. The same problem affects floating point by the way.

A third solution would be to use a divider by 5. It would cost around 32 3-bits adder depending on the algorithm, which is really not that bad. It also gives you the full precision, i.e. an error only on the lsb. Xilinx has cores for division available.

### Update

I am quite sorry if my fixed point explanations are unclear, I will freely admit I'm not sure about the best way to explain it.

First, do not scale by *10*, or any other non-power-of-2. While not wrong, you usually have to multiply/divide by your scale factor, which is trivial for powers of 2, but not for other numbers.

Consider the theory first. Let's say you have real numbers `a` and `b`, you should see that:

```
a * b = c
a*2^N * b*2^M = d = c * 2^(N+M)
```

So if you scale 2 numbers before a multiplication, it only changes the result by another scaling factor. That is the basis of fixed-point arithmetic, scale the operands and keep track of the scaling of the output. However, we operate only on integers, so we don't use `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`, but a trucated, rounded or approximated version of these values:

```
round(a*2^N) * round(b*2^N) = e approx d approx round(c*2^(N+M))
```

In subsequent calculations, you keep `e`. When you need to get a real number back, usually outside the FPGA when you interpret you data, you would divide `e` by 2^(N+M). Of course, you made an error by using fixed point (or floating point for that matter), it's equal to `c - e/2^(N+M)`, using larger `N` and `M` will reduce the error.

Back to your example, using a scaling of 2^8. Wherever you multiply by 0.2, you multiply by 51 (round(0.2*2^8)) instead. Your result will be scaled by 2^8, it's up to you if you want to keep it that way or scale to another scaling factor (like 2^0).

Comment: If precision matters there is also a decimal floating format. This is used in PowerPC architectures for finacial applications. I haven't looked into the details yet, but I assume it needs more resouces than binary floating point :)

Comment: @jonathan As for 32 bit, usually 24bit is for fraction and 8 bit for exponent, so how to represent it as fixed-point number like signal number:ufixed( 23 downto 8) ; or else

Comment: @NabeelAnjum, what you describe is single-precision floating point. In fixed point, you decide where the fractional part begin. A 32 bits may be 32 bits integer, 0 bit fractional (your normal integer). You may decide to have 16 bits integer, 16 bits fractional, allowing you to represent (considering unsigned) number from 0 to 65535.99998 with a precision of 1/2^16. In that case, bits 31 downto 16 would be the integer part, bits 15 downto 0 the fractional. You decide how much integer/fractional bits you need based on the design's requirements

Comment: I want to give fixed input from C code which will go to my FPGA . FPGA take that fixed point value as 8 bits . So this is my question I am actually asking !! I am using unsigned (7 downto 0 ) input in FPGA . so       data : input unsigned (7 downto 0) ;

Comment: If you want to represent 0.2 in a 8 bits number, then I would use 205 (0.2*2^10). If you want the result to be the same scale as the operand, divide it by 2^10. For example, 0.2 * 1234 => 205 * 1234 / 2^10 = 252970 / 1024 => 247. The "real" answer would be 0.2 * 1234 = 246.8, which is close to the fixed point approximation.

Comment: @NabeelAnjum 0.5*3, following your convention, would be 0x00800000 * 0x00000003 = 0x01800000, which is 1.5 once you convert back to real: 0x01800000 => 25165824/2^24 = 1.5

Comment: You convert wherever you can't deal with fixed-point. In a lot of case, it's never, you just keep fixed-point everywhere. But if you export these fixed point values to a computer or something, you may want to convert them to regular float.

Comment: r <= to_real(to_float(FIXED_INPUT));
 x <= to_real(to_float(Data_in));
     s <= x * r ; 
    M_AXIS_TDATA <= to_slv(to_float(s)); 
is it  a right method ? whereas r , x, s are real signals, and remaining are 32 bit std_logic_Vector signals

Comment: Can't help you there, I never used `real` in VHDL except testbench or memory initialization, but you should need an IP core to convert fixed-point to floating point. The conversion should really be done outside of the FPGA, or on a microcontroller **only** if it can't deal with floating point.

Comment: This is the problem: Xilinx don't have the built in IP for fixed to floating point. they have float to float, float to fixed or so...

Comment: But why do you need float out of your IP? Just keep the fixed point.

Comment: As you have answered :  0.5*3, following your convention, would be 0x00800000 * 0x00000003 = 0x01800000, which is 1.5 once you convert back to real: 0x01800000 => 25165824/2^24 = 1.5  

So i can send 0.5 from that IP which would convert this float to fixed 0x00800000. and after getting multiplied  , my output will be 0x018000000. so this will be my std_logic-vector output. so how can i justify others that treat that value as fixed point representation. not as a normal hexa decimal

Comment: You tell them it's fixed point. Hardware design is not about sugar-coating like software. When I make an IP, I tell others how to use it, and they have to live with it. I also make sure my IPs are as small and effective as possible, so I require that data I export/import is as close as possible to what I will actually process.

Comment: Also, looking at Xilinx Floating Point IP (http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/floating_point/v7_0/pg060-floating-point.pdf), page 31 says they support fixed-point to floating point.

Comment: You should experiment or ask a question. I don't do enough C to answer without testing the code.

Comment: Indeed..  this is the best solution . Fixed that :)

Comment: @JonathanDrolet

 z= 2+ [0.2 * (4-10) ] = 0.8 . 0.8 in fixed point format ( 0x000000cd) (24 integer, 8 fractional format ): 0.2 is 0x00000033 in fixed point format . (24 integer, 8 fractional format ) but I am getting [0x00000002 + (0x00000033 * (0x00000004-0x0000000A) ] = FFFFFED0. (which is negative number). How to represent that output as 0.8 again.

Comment: When you add, your quantities need to have the same scaling. [0.2 * (4-10)] => 0x00000033*(0x00000004-0x0000000A) = 0xffffffce, a number with 8 bits fractionnals equal to -1.17187. To add 2, you must also represent it with 8 bits fractionnal: 0x00000200 + 0xffffffce = 0x000000ce, which is equivalent to 0.8046875.